# Get inverse list of matches from MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to find a way to use a set of data from a subquery to search a table for results that do not match the set of data.

Here is the table definition:

```sql
create table users (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  created timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY key(id)
);

create table logs (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int(11),
  triggered tinyint(1),
  PRIMARY key(id)
);

create table events (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  created timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  user_id int(11),
  event_name varchar(200),
  PRIMARY key(id)
);
```

I wish to pull a list of users who were created in a certain date range, who have an average triggered value of > 0.5, and who do not have the logged_in event. I've built the below query to the best of my skillset to get a list of users who *do* have the logged_in event, however I cannot work out how to do the inverse:

```sql
-- Returns all users who have a logged_in event from a subset of users who have an AVG triggered of > 0.5 from a subset of users who were created in the last 32 days. 
SELECT
   DISTINCT user_id
FROM
   events
WHERE
   event_name = 'logged_in'
AND
   user_id IN (
      SELECT
          user_id
      FROM
      (
        SELECT
            user_id, triggered
          FROM
            logs
          WHERE
            user_id IN
            (
              SELECT
                id
              FROM
                users
              WHERE
                created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 32 day)
            )
      ) AS raw_logs
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING
         AVG(triggered) > 0.5     
   )
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87aee/3)

On the fiddle this returns user ID 2 (a user with a logged in event, AVG > 0.5 and created in the last 32 days), however I want to return user ID 4 (a user who does not have a logged in event, AVG > 0.5 and created in the last 32 days).

*Edit note: My previous version of this question was misleading, this version should make more sense*

Comment: I believe I could do this with a `JOIN` with `logs` and `users` in the parent query, however this seems unclean as the data I need (I think) already exists in the subquery result.

Comment: whats your expected result?

Comment: Maybe you need in `SELECT logs.* FROM logs JOIN users ON users.id = logs.user_id WHERE users.active = 1 AND users.vip = 1`?

Comment: Or maybe you need 'or'? We don't really know because you haven't really said.

Comment: sorry all, my entire question was poorly put so I've re-written the whole thing. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up resolving this in the cleanest way I can think using another conditional subquery further back in the pack to effectively remove those users earlier.

```sql
SELECT
      user_id
FROM
(
   SELECT
      user_id, triggered
   FROM
      logs
   WHERE
      user_id IN
      (
         SELECT
            id
         FROM
            users
         WHERE
            created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 32 day)
      )
   AND
      user_id NOT IN
   (
      SELECT
         user_id
      FROM
         events
      WHERE
         event_name = 'logged_in'
   )
) AS raw_logs
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING
   AVG(triggered) > 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to offer this as an answer, but at first site, and completed untested, but perhaps `MINUS` the list from your query against a list of all users might be worth a try.

```
SELECT id user_id
FROM users
MINUS
/* Your query from above */
SELECT
   DISTINCT user_id
FROM
   events
WHERE
   event_name = 'logged_in'
AND
   user_id IN (
      SELECT
          user_id
      FROM
      (
        SELECT
            user_id, triggered
          FROM
            logs
          WHERE
            user_id IN
            (
              SELECT
                id
              FROM
                users
              WHERE
                created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 32 day)
            )
      ) AS raw_logs
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING
         AVG(triggered) > 0.5     
   )
```

Comment: Thanks @TenG. This is a valid solution, however it felt a bit dirty to repeat the query again. I've posted the solution I ended up using below.